# How to remove sjp.lmer loess line

Tags: r, plot, lme4

I am attempting to fit my lmer predicted line to data using jsp.lmer, it works except the LOESS line is automatically added to the plot.

I've tried specifying

```
sjp.lmer(fit,"fe.pred",showLoess=FALSE)
```

which should remove the line, but the argument is instead ignored.

Here is an example that should work to reproduce the problem.

```
library(lme4)
library(sjPlot)
politeness<-read.csv("http://www.bodowinter.com/tutorial/politeness_data.csv")
politeness.model <- lmer(frequency ~ attitude + (1|subject), data=politeness)
sjp.lmer(politeness.model,type="fe.pred",showLoess=FALSE)
```

Comment: I replicated your code, and I'm not seeing a loess line, if I set `showLoess` to true, I see another line on the plot.What happens if you set showloess to true?

Comment: Same here. Package version? (sjPlot 1.8.2, ggplot2 1.0.1.9003 here)

Comment: @BenBolker I get this error message when I run the code. (sjPlot version 1.8.1, ggplot1 version 1.0.0)  Error in sjp.lmer(politeness.model, type = "fe.pred", showLoess = FALSE) :   unused argument (showLoess = FALSE) I'll update my packages and see if that helps.

Comment: can you please post `sessionInfo()` results, or at least the result of `packageVersion("sjPlot")` ?

Comment: @BenBolker Updated package and it's fixed!

Comment: voting to close as "no longer reproducible"